# get value of datepicker directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

This was the code I was using before...

```
<div class="date_menu" ng-repeat="singledate in dates">
    <p>
    {{singledate}}

    <input type="radio" name="filterDateChosen2" ng-model="$parent.radioResult" ng-value="singledate">
    </p>
</div></div>
```

This displayed a list of dates in the form of radio buttons. This saved the selected date in `$parent.radioResult` where I was able to then access it with...

```
<button ng-click="getVar(radioResult)"...
```

But now, I want to use jQuery datepicker instead...

```
myApp.directive('calendar', function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       element.datepicker({
           inline: true,
           dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
           onSelect: function(dateText) {
               var modelPath = $(this).attr('ng-model');
               var val = $(this).attr('ng-value');
               putObject(modelPath, val, scope, dateText);
               scope.$apply();
           }
       });
   }
});
```

This works, if I select a date, the input box will show it...

```
<input calendar ng-model="$parent.radioResult" />
```

But the problem is, when I use...

```
<button ng-click="getVar(radioResult)"...
```

It does not get the value, and I cannot figure out why? What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a JQuery Datepicker which is not in the Angular context so you need to bring it into the Angular's context first by setting the selected date to the variable on the scope like below

```
 $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.dateValue = selectedDate;
 });
```